# how can my button open a new tab?

Tags: jquery

I have a basic jquery issue. Just trying to make this link open in a new tab/window. I have added _blank but it does not go to a new page. Any ideas?

```js
   $('#link13').click(function() {

    window.location.href= 'https://www.google.com','_blank';

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="link13">See the Resources</button>
```

Comment: Try `window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#link13').click(function() {
    window.open(
      'https://www.google.com',
      '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.open():`

```
var win = window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');
if (win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
} else {
    //Browser has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

Depending on the browsers implementation this will work
see this if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can use following:

`<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('http://google.com','_blank')"> Google</button>`

Pure HTML Method:

`<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>`